# Patents need to be non-obvious, but this patent is clearly obvious

Tags: non-obviousness, usd791006

Patented items are supposed to be non-obvious inventions. However, this patent would seem to be frivolous, consisting of hot glue and a brass casing used to produce a type of bracelet.

In reference to the patent: [USD791006](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD791006S1/en?oq=USD791006)

How is this patentable?

Comment: @Maca If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino It wasn't an answer. It's a comment because the question doesn't make sense, and so needs to be clarified before being answered. Hence the close vote too.

Comment: @Maca I kind of took your comment and drafted an answer. In my defense, I had exactly the same thought.

Comment: @EricShain No problem! It's better than leaving it open and unresponded to.

Answer (score 1):

Design patents **are definitely subject to obviousness**. A glass beverage bottle with an indented right-hand spiral would presumably be obvious in light of a similar bottle with a left-hand spiral. Many millions of dollars hung in the balance on whether or not Apples's D618,677 design patent on the iPhone was or wasn't obvious in light of previous art. Regarding the patent in question, on google patents you will see ten cited items listed that the examiner found in searching for things that might show the bracelet as obvious in light of.

It is true that it has not always been clear how to apply the non-obviousness criteria to designs; and rejections on 35 USC 103 are not as frequent in design application as in utility applications. See [this PatentlyO article](https://patentlyo.com/patent/2014/09/%C2%A7103-obvious-compared.html) titled "Design Patents §103 – Obvious to Whom and As Compared to What?".

Comment: I deleted my answer as yours is both better and more correct.